# ajax post request url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

there is happening a bug in my app that isnt the first time that happen to be, i cant figure out why is doing it. I have a post request being made in a specific route, but in my app, instead making the ajax call to my specific url is send to the current url from tha page. 
My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: '/galleries/heatMap/'.idGallery,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {img: url, _token: token, idGallery: idGallery, productStat: productStat, tagStat: tagStat}
}).done(function (msg) {
    console.log("Save HeatMap");

    tagStat = {
        title: "",
        clicks: 0,
        product_id: 0
    };
    productStat = {
        clicks: 0,
        product_id: 0
    };
}).fail(function () {
    console.log("Error ocurred");

});
```

My current url where im making the post is: http://domain.com/models/1/embed/

And for some reason the post is being made to '../models/1/embed/', instead the url of the ajax. Does someone have a idea what is happening?

Comment: If you are using form and input type as submit remove type submit and try again...

Comment: once post your html code too..where this function is being called from

Comment: Do you have any type of caching enabled?

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying your url as

```
 url: '/galleries/heatMap/'.idGallery,
```

replace this with this, it may be work

```
 url: '/galleries/heatMap/'+idGallery,
```

Comment: and put dataType:"json" in the ajax

Answer (score 1):

Check you debug console.

Try using full path here:

`url: 'http://domain.com/galleries/heatMap/'+idGallery,`